# Twitter's typeahead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, typeahead

I am trying to add twitter's typeahead plugin to my rails application. I have downloaded the typeahead.bundle.js and placed it in vendor/assets/javascripts directory. And I have added //= require typeahead.bundle to app/assets/javascripts/application.js. Then I put the first example given there

```
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>
```

on one of my views and the following javascript on
 app/assets/javascripts/example.js

but nothing happens when i try to type characters, not even on the logs. Thanks for your help

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substrRegex;

    matches = [];

    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {

        matches.push({ value: str });
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```